Location Tab not visible on properties
Even after having the code {4a7ded0a-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103} in the Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers{4a7ded0a-ad25-11d0-98a8-0800361b1103}. Still not be able to see the Location tab.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
